# react list rendering failed

Tags: reactjs, frontend

environment：react 17.x、umi 3.5.21 
In this code below, I send a request and build an array of components, using `console.log(hosCardArr)` in `then` has content

```
let hosCardArr: any[] = [];
    useEffect(() => {
        getHosList({ _location: location, _level: level }).then(function (
            response: returnHosInfo[],
        ) {
            let arr: any[] = [];

            for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                let e: returnHosInfo = response[i]
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    arr.push(<HosCard name={e.name} level={e.level} openTime={e.openTime} domLocation='left' />)
                } else {
                    arr.push(<HosCard name={e.name} level={e.level} openTime={e.openTime} domLocation='right' />)
                }
            }

            hosCardArr = arr
        });
    });
```

In this code below, I render the array, using `console.log(hosCardArr)` in `<div><div/>` the result is `[]`

```
<div>{hosCardArr}</div>
```

The end result is that the elements in the array are not displayed

Comment: try console logging the array at the end of the function and check if your function is working.

Comment: `console.log` has content，I found `hosCardArr` is empty arr in `<div>{hosCardArr}</div>`, do you have a good idea

Comment: try using the `map` method in `div`

Comment: The problem with your code is on each render you are setting `hosCardArr` to empty array. so it will never populate the data. you need to utilise the state of the component and have it updated using usEffect.

Comment: Yes, this is problem about data flow, I had solve this.

Answer (score 1):

The focus of this question is on data flow，If I don't use `state`, it will render the array empty and not updated

```
    const [hosCardArr, setHosCardArr] = useState<any[]>([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        getHosList({ _location: location, _level: level }).then(function (
            response: returnHosInfo[],
        ) {
            let arr: any[] = [];

            for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                let e: returnHosInfo = response[i]
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    arr.push(<HosCard name={e.name} level={e.level} openTime={e.openTime} domLocation='left' />)
                } else {
                    arr.push(<HosCard name={e.name} level={e.level} openTime={e.openTime} domLocation='right' />)
                }
            }
            setHosCardArr(arr)
        });
    }, []);
```

Answer (score -1):

you must use .map function to render each item of the array , like this :

```
return (
   <>
     {
        hosCardArr.map((hos,index) =>
          <div key={index}>{hos}</div>
        );
     }
   </>
)
```